# Display HTML content inside a table cell - BIRT report designer

Tags: birt

I have a dataset in which one of the column has html tags. When I try to bind the data column with a cell inside a table, the data is being displayed as it is - I see the html tags like  < br >,< br > in the cell. Is there a way I can get rid of the tags and display the data with proper formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
But a `data item` does not work for this.
You'll have to use a `text item`, and inside the text item, reference the data as `row["MY_COLUMN"]` (you know, what I mean). It is important to switch the text item's Content Type from the default `Plain` to `HTML`.

Comment: Thank you. I used the text item instead of data item and referenced the data as :<VALUE-OF  format="HTML">row[""MY_COLUMN"]</VALUE-OF>.  This removed the tags and displayed the data as desired.